# Bootstrap tooltip not working in mobile resolutions

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap's tooltip doesnt work in a mobile resolution?.It is working fine in a desktop and laptop resolutions.I have bootstrap's bunddle javascript file linked,before that i have attached the jQuery javascript file.Here is the HTML:

```
<span class="customURL-copy copy" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Copy To Clipboard">
    <i class="far fa-clone"></i>
  </span>
<script src="/scripts/lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/lib/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
}) 


$(".copy").click(function(event){
    $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'Copied!').tooltip('show');
})
```